# how to choose all same row with abap alv

Tags: abap, alv

When I choose one row , and I choose all "001000000224" automatically. how do I do it ?

Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wKGe.png)

I have a question in the sap community
https://answers.sap.com/questions/13316914/how-to-choose-all-same-row.html

Comment: you wanna autoselect all the rows with the same ID when you select single one?

Comment: yes . you are right

Comment: well, it's rather weird requirement and will be rather performance-heavy but if you want, the Jigang [in his comment](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13316914/how-to-choose-all-same-row.html?childToView=13319301#comment-13319301) described it pretty well. Just follow this implementation path and ask more specific question about what's going wrong on what step

Comment: So post your solution, so that other member can make use of it

Comment: I have a summary with Chinese blog.    Sometimes I hope I can write it by English blog. But I don't know which blog is fit. Thanks.   alv monitor  is used  by me . https://blog.csdn.net/beyond911/article/details/115027491